# Why are apps slowing down my phone just by being installed?

Tags: performance

I have about 50 apps installed on my phone (not counting system apps). And my phone is absolutely unusable this way. Everything lags so bad that I can barely even enter my lockscreen pattern. I assumed this was because the apps can magically run in the background as services or whatever, but after freezing about 40 of them and making sure that only a very few services were running like whatsapp, my alarmclock app and my firewall app. My phone is still extremely slow.

Why is that?

Back when I only had these 10 apps installed that are running right now, everything worked pretty smoothly.

So what is wrong? A frozen app shouldn't have an impact on performance in such a way. Is there any way to get it fast again?

I've already removed as much preinstalled apps/bloatware as possible and cleaned the system using SD-Maid and used Autorun Manager to disable a ton of receivers that could start some apps. But it is still really slow.

Comment: Which Android device and Android version are you using?

Comment: Does that even matter? I had this problem on both smartphones that I've owned until now. The current one is an LG G2 Mini, stock ROM, Android 4.4.2.

Comment: You could try using [Perfmon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.perfmon)  to study which app is consuming most resources

Comment: if we goona find exactly what is the problem we really need more infos ,like logs ,power consumption , Storage benchmarks ,which apps are frozen full list if possible ,what bloatware did you remove ? ram memory usage ,how many apps are on your SDcard ,what kind of SDcard you're using  ?

Comment: How much RAM is free in Running Service ? I experience lag when my phone does not have enough space in internal storage. How much space is left in your internal storage ?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Information provided by you is scant. Requests for information to help surely a solution have not been answered. How then is it possible to arrive at a solution that works?

Comment: Sorry. Yes my phones are all rooted and it looks like there is actually only 170MB of RAM free when I close all apps (the normal way). Wtf? My phone should have about 1GB. About Perfmon, is there a free alternative?

Comment: Holy crap, my Whatsapp uses 736MB of my RAM. What the hell? Okay that must be the issue. I could probably just delete all my messages, but I don't really want to. I need to search through them regularely. I guess i could make a backup, but I heard that after some time it gets impossible to merge the backed up message database with the new one because whatsapp changes a lot and I'm really scared of that. Any ideas?

Comment: Perfmon alternative IDK...It is one of a kind

Comment: Since you are rooted, suggest install wakelock detector to see what is consuming resources when screen is off and perfmon to see when it is on.You will at least be able to pin point top issues and then one can take it further. That was my suggestion and I don't have time to elaborate as answer

Comment: Your what's app concern would be better addressed as a separate question (do check existing questions ). You can link this question in that to give background. Your concern now on this is only heard by people who carr to read comments

Answer (score 3):

Phones use [Solid State Drives (SSDs)](http://ocz.com/consumer/ssd-guide/ssd-vs-hdd) for storage instead of traditional Hard Drives (HDDs). This is because carrying and jostling HDDs can cause hardware problems.

Solid State Drives, however, [get slow as you fill them up](http://www.howtogeek.com/165542/why-solid-state-drives-slow-down-as-you-fill-them-up/). So when you start to fill up your phone, its storage gets slower. This means that it takes longer to read the code from storage into RAM to execute.

It should also be noted that [the description on Autorun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun&hl=en) says that some apps will just attempt to restart themselves after it kills them. This constant restarting-killing behavior could possibly be even harder on system resources that just letting the background app run, so be careful which apps you kill.

Some background tasks help apps start-up faster too. I can start up a heck of a lot faster if I've already updated my app while you weren't using it. Instead of waiting for my app to get all of the data it needs when you open it, it grabs it in the background and can just display it when you open the app.

Also, if your device has very little RAM, then it can only hold a couple of apps in there at a time. If the apps you're opening have been erased from RAM, you phone has to erase another app from RAM and use that space for the new app.

Basically, there are a ton of reasons why your phone could be acting slow, and it's probably a combination of them that's causing your phone to act so poorly.

Comment: I already moved most of the frozen apps to the SD card and it's still the same. Also: As far as I know, SSDs don't really get slower the more data is on them. On my notebook for example I get full read/write speeds until the drive is full.

Comment: @Forivin Check my link, the benchmarks don't lie.

Comment: My internal storage and my SD card are only filled by about 60% each anyway...

Comment: this really shouldn't be a comparison between SSDs and HDDs. They both slow down when close to full, HDD's much more significantly than SSDs

Comment: android phones don't use SSD's as their storage that's totally false ,android phones uses eMMC flash storage , slower than SSDs

Comment: I go with @sonictt1. I too experience lag in my Nexus 5 when my internal storage has only around 1 GB, I have experienced lag in whatsapp and keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You might be having lots of data, including pictures and videos, and others that is media from social apps, including WhatsApp and FaceBook .. get a back up of that data, free some space,

also delete unnacesiry apps,  like those used for cleanups,

hope this helps you run the phone acting smooth again,

Answer (score 0):

As you install apps, they are allowed to run in the background. This takes up quite a lot of ram, and will slow down your phone. Do not use a task killer, as the apps use even more ram to restart themselves. The only solution is to delete some of the apps. To find the ones using a lot of ram go to

> Settings->Apps->Running

Look for the high ram usage apps, and delete them. As a last resort, factory reset your phone.